# Importing objects form blender to unity correctly

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, game-engine, blender

I have recently done few 3d objects in blender and I want to import them int unity3d. I know the basics: that I should export it to FBX file. But I wonder if there are any other things that are very important while exporting to unity? For example where should i position center of my object(near the ground or in the center)?

Comment: Something you may need to pay attention to is the export settings for FBX - you may need to change the forward and up direction and check off "Apply Transformations" in order to have the model correctly oriented in Unity. (Blender uses a Z-up coordinate system, whereas Unity uses a Y-up system.) This can cause headaches if you plan on moving the object in Unity based on `transform` directions. Ensuring the rotation of the model in Unity is correct can be very useful in cases where parenting under an empty GameObject is not feasible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you want the origin to be the bottom of the character (feet), and another good idea when importing is to make the model a child of an empty object before saving it as a prefab. That parent empty object will then have driver scripts that control stuff like movement and animation.

EDIT: This is one example of why you might want to do the empty parent method, but it isn't directly applicable to your question: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-FixZAxisIsUp.html

Answer (score 1):

1) apply location, rotation and scale.
2) set the origin of the model to the bottom.
3) Delete camera and lights